# Wordpress: Double Vertical Scrollbars on pages with parallax scrolling. How can I fix this?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, scrollbar, parallax

Newbie at coding and I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. I'm using this parallax scroll plugin

https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/adamrob-parallax-scroll

with the Customizr theme and it's causing two vertical scrollbars on my website (http://www.udvalbatbayar.com/).

The main scrollbar appears only when you scroll near the header.

All of the overflow-y's are hidden, and I can't seem to locate the problem (online or in the code)

How do I get rid of the extra scrollbar? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .page-template-full-width-php #main-wrapper {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

... then the inner scrollbar will disappear. Also, you probably should remove it for another media queries.